# what if I don't want to return anything in jquery ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails

I am calling ajax function

```
$.ajax({
     url: $.grails.createLink('class', 'action'),
     data: {id: id1},
     async: false
});
```

so I am calling grails method here

```
def action = {

}
```

now at the end of this action method if I don't return anything I get js error 'Sorry, Error occurred' so explicitly I specified '**render ""**' at the end of action method.

Is there any way to avoid render?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Grails, but have you tried `render(status: 200)`?

Comment: What so you see if you use just `return` instead of `render ""`?

Comment: render(status:200) works. return gives same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't return anything, grails will try and render a view `grails-app/views/controller/action.gsp`

I expect this doesn't exist, so you'll get a 404

You can add an empty view, `render` a blank template, or do what you are doing (the shortest option)

Answer (score 0):

```
def action = {
    render "ok"
}
```

should work